# Create missing switch cases in AppCode - formatting

Tags: objective-c, code-formatting, appcode

There's a great "Create missing switch cases" feature in AppCode. How can I change formatting of the added cases? I would like to add new lines before breaks.
Currently I'm getting the following code:

```
    switch(a) {
        case A:break;
        case B:break;
    }
```

I would like to have instead:

```
    switch(a) {
        case A:
            break;
        case B:
            break;
    }
```

Ideally, it would be great to have an option to replace *break* with *return* for all the cases at once. Is there a way to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Preferences** (CMD+,) and find next:
[image: screenshot]
I'm using EAP but there same options in latest release. Just search for "Code style".

Comment: I already have this option unchecked. Unfortunately, it doesn't affect the "Create missing switch cases" feature.

Comment: Submit issue to JetBrains tracker